# React - Material ui tooltip arrow is not align to the buttons/container

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use Material Ui tooltip inside Appbar, but the tooltip is not aligned to the icon or to the container

[image]

the same when using the simple tooltip example from docs :

```
  <Tooltip title="Delete" arrow>
      <IconButton>
          <NotificationsOutlinedIcon color="primary" />
      </IconButton>
  </Tooltip>
```

the issue is happening only when using inside an appbar
and also because the Text Typography that uses flex-grow, when I remove the text is working,  how can I fix that?

my code:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
  <AppBar position="static">
    <Toolbar>
      {logo}
      <Typography className={classes.title}>
        <ViewDropDownMenu/>
      </Typography>
        <Tooltip title="tooltip" arrow>
            <IconButton aria-label="tooltip">
            <DeleteIcon color="primary" />
        </IconButton>
       </Tooltip>
      {/* </div> */}
    </Toolbar>
  </AppBar>
</div>
```

style :

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default
    },
    appbar: {
      justifyContent: 'center',
      height: '100%'
    },
    menuButton: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2)
    },
    title: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      textAlign: 'center',  
      color: theme.palette.text.primary
    },
    logo: {
      maxWidth: 79
    }
  })
);
```

so when I remove the classes.title

Comment: Where does your `Tooltip` component render? Do you put it in a `div` or something?

Comment: Also, what is your value for `props.placement`? You can see [here](https://material-ui.com/api/tooltip/) your options

Comment: @DavidBuzatu.  updated the question , found that the issue in when using appbar

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen in the [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/#PositionedTooltips.js), you should specify the placement of your `arrow`. You want to put it bottom, in the center. So your `placement` value should be:

```
<Tooltip
  arrow
  title={props.title}
  color="inherit"
  placement={"bottom"} // here you should specify your placement value
  PopperProps={{
    disablePortal: shouldDisablePortal
  }}
  open={open}
  disableFocusListener={shouldDisableFocusListener}
  disableHoverListener={props.disableHoverListener}
>
  <span>{props.children}</span>
</Tooltip>
```

**UPDATE**
(comments)

`Tooltip` is positioned `absolute`. It probably has a `right` property of `0`. If you modify your `scrollbar` width, it will get positioned relative to that new width, making your `tooltip` appear a bit to the left.

**DISCLAIMER**

I am not saying this is the explanation, but I would assume its something related to this or `overflow`.

Comment: HI , i updated the question ,the issue is with using Appbar , not related to placement

Comment: I did recreate your example (without `ViewDropDownMenu`) and it worked just fine. You should take a look at that component and see if its styling does not interfere with your `Appbar` and, implicitly, `Tooltip`

Comment: hi thanks . it happens also when I removed the viewdropdown at all and replace it with simple typography. it smth with the flex-grow I think

Comment: `flex-grow` only tells how much the element should grow relative to the other elements. I believe you might have some kind of CSS conflict. Could you create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io)? There, I could see exactly your workflow, css and you can hide whatever you consider non-important

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-react-material-ui-forked-mwqx4?file=/src/Header.tsx:1118-1125.   here its working.. wired

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and preparing the sandbox! I had the same results: it works. This could mean that you:
1. Overwrote your button styling somewhere else (check your website with the inspect tool and see if anything strange appears)
2. Overwrote your `appbar` styling.

Please check these two things and come back

Comment: thank ,   i added the theme base to the sandbox now I see that when I remove the 

     '*::-webkit-scrollbar': {
        width: '1.3%',
        maxWidth: '5px'
      },

from global css (from material theme. -> main.ts ) its working in my machine .. but how it can be related to tooltips

Comment: That's interesting. I do not think that should be the expected behavior. I would pursue you into making an issue on [github](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues?q=webkit-scrollbar). I honestly don't know why is that happening. Maybe changing your scrollbar shifts `absolute` positioned element to the left (with your values for width and maxWidth)

Comment: A hacky way to fix this would be to give your tooltip a negative 'margin' of -5px